# How can I remove characters from get variables before sending form data?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, get

I have a form where users enter the amount of rent to pay.

```
<form action="search_results.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="rent" value="$" />
</form>
```

I am using jQuery to keep the dollar sign in the field when the user enters their rent amount.

```
$('input[name=rent]').keyup(function() {
   $(this).val(function(i,v) {
     return '$' + v.replace('$',''); //remove existing, add back.
   });
 });
```

When the form sends to the search_results.php page, it sends to the url with the following get variable attached to it:

> http://www.domain.com/search_results.php?rent=%24

When the page begins to load, it shows the following error message:

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   /nfs/c09/h01/mnt/12345/domains/www.domain.com/html/search_results.php
>   on line 551

I'm pretty sure the error occurs because my sql statement is using the $_GET['rent'] variable to sort through all the listings with less than the rent amount entered, and it cannot do that with the dollar sign in it.

How can I remove the dollar sign character from the input field before it sends to the search_results.php page OR how can I remove the %24 from the url on the search_results.php page and then reload the page?

Comment: Duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822718/change-value-of-a-field-on-submit-using-javascript

Comment: @Raman - While I am open to all suggestions, I was more preferential to a PHP based solution, so it's not a duplicate of that post

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $('input[name=rent]').val($('input[name=rent]').val().replace('$', ''))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $('input[name=rent]').val(function(index, valueWith$){
    return valueWith$.substring(1);
  });
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is a better solution - You can filter the data after he passed:

```
$rent = str_replace('$','',$_GET['rent']);
$rent = str_replace('%24','',$rent);
```

Btw - I suggest you to learn more about SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. In this specific example, What is your suggestion in regards to SQL injection protection? Do I just use the mysql_real_escape_string() function on each of my variables in the sql statement?

Comment: Well, it is not the full answer. You should learn what affects the SQL query like the ` character and such. Filtering the data in the code itself is much much more safer then filtering it on the html page, which people can disable JavaScript on it. And another suggestion - Move to mysqli or PDO, I think that mysql is going to be depreciated. Btw, mark the answer as accepted. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

This errors occurs because you are not giving mysqli resource to it.

```
if (!mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
```

You are simply calling this function like that: `mysqli_error();`